Why unity requires java 17 and gives an error: "required version java11"
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
I tried to install java 17, but Unity said: Incompatible Java version '17', expected Java version 64-Bit '11.0.14.1'.
Android development requires JDK 11 64-bit. Having Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installed is not sufficient.
I downloaded java 11, but this error occured
and i also set 'JAVA_HOME' and 'path' to the Java 11

Same problem here.
If you see in the Android Doc to use Gradle 8.4:
https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-3-0-release-notes
JDK 17
Unity docs refers to 8.4
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html

It seems you installed JRE instead of JDK

Having Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installed is not sufficient

If so, try downloading JDK from official website
